# How to run the equivalent of "sudo update-rc.d redis_6379 defaults" in CentOS?

Tags: redis, centos, daemon

I am installing redis on CentOS. In order to daemonize redis, their documentation says to run the following command after completing a few configuration steps.

```
sudo update-rc.d redis_6379 defaults
```

However, this command is not available on CentOS. I was able to complete all the prior steps using the CentOS equivalent commands except for this one.

I read that `insserv` or `chkconfig` are the equivalents on CentOS. `insserv` was not found on my CentOS. I am left with `chkconfig` which I do have. But how to run the equivalent of above command? Do I need to be in a certain directory first?

I cd'd to the following directory.

```
cd /etc/rc.d/rc?.d
```

Then ran all of these commands none of which worked.

```
chkconfig --defaults redis_6379   //--> --defaults: unknown option
chkconfig --add redis_6379        //--> service redis_6379 does not support chkconfig
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For anyone that ran into this issue, I found these guide to install redis on linux: https://discuss.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/205308418-How-to-install-and-use-Redis-on-Linux

Answer (score 0):

```
~$ [sudo] systemctl enable redis_6379
~$ [sudo] systemctl start redis_6379
```

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65398/converting-update-rc-d-redis-6379-defaults-to-chkconfig-command